# Is there a way to quickly jump between equations in normal mode in vim-latex (suite)

Tags: vim-latex

I'm looking for a keystroke to jump to previous or next equation environment. Is there one in vim-latex suite?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you mean with `vim-latex suite`. I'm using `vimtex` with `coc-vimtex` and `coc-texlab`. I guess that `vimtex` is the same. Anyway this is in the manuals of `vimtex`:
[image]

But as already mentioned, I don't know if we use the same plugin.

Comment: this is late, but potentially OP was talking about [vim-latex](https://vim-latex.sourceforge.net) which is separate from vimtex.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer and the link to `vim-latex`! :)